# How to print cascaded names of functions pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, display

I was working of functions pointers examples and I developed 4 simple functions and assigned them to a function pointer array, then I ran the code and worked for the 4 functions, but then I thought to also print the names of the functions.

I learned about `__func__` and it only prints the name of the current function, so is there anyway to assign `__func__` to the function pointer or another method to print the names of the functions?

This is the example I'm working on right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int add(int x, int y);
int sub(int x, int y);
int mul(int x, int y);
int divide(int x, int y);


int main() {
    int m = 6;
    int n = 10;
    int res,i;


    int (*fun[4])(int,int)={add,sub,mul,divide};

    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("result of %s operation\n",__func__=fun[i]);
    }
}

int add(int x, int y) {
int result = x + y;
return result;
}

int sub(int x, int y) {
int result = x - y;
return result;
}

int mul(int x, int y) {
int result = x * y;
return result;
}

int divide(int x, int y) {
int result = x / y;
return result;
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to assign the `__func__` to the functions pointer but of course it's not working.

Comment: "I learned about func", what do you mean by that? What do you mean by "func"? Instead of describing the code, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and *show* us instead.

Comment: Compiled code doesn't contain functions and symols names by default. You can use some macros to create constant strings containing functions names included in the compiled binary.

Comment: Please provide your code my crystall ball is not working today.

Comment: Ahh, your slipping @AndreKampling, with your normal X-ray vision, you should be able to see his screen from here...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Probably a mis-spelled `__func__`, which expands to the name of the enclosing function.

Comment: SO goes bananas when faced with double underscore outside code formatting. Fixed. But this question is still too vague. If you are looking for a way to know where function pointers are pointing, you have to design one yourself. If you wish to return a `const char*` to a local `__func__` then that's fine, they are guaranteed to have static storage duration.

Comment: Please provide what output you expect from printf("result of %s operation\n"....

Comment: I'm expecting to substitute the name of each function in "%s" location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__func__` constant in every function is only accessible in runtime. Meaning that if you want to use that one, you have to grab it while calling the function. Like this:

```
typedef int calc_func_t (int x, int y, const char** func);

int add(int x, int y, const char** func);
...

calc_func_t* fun[4] = {add,sub,mul,divide};

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    const char* func;
    int result = fun[i](1,1,&func);
    printf("result of %s operation %d\n", func, result);
}

...

int add(int x, int y, const char** func) 
{
  int result = x + y;
  *func = __func__;
  return result;
}

...
```

If you wish to know what the functions are named at compile-time and then later on use that information, the easiest and best way would be to create a look-up table:

```
typedef struct
{
  calc_func_t* func;
  const char*  name;
} calc_func_info_t;

const calc_func_info_t func_info [] =
{
  {add, "add"},
  {sub, "sub"},
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiled code doesn't contain functions and symols names by default. You can use some macros to create constant strings containing functions names to be included in the compiled binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function call type
typedef void fn_call();

// record describing one function
typedef struct fn_record {

    const char *name; // function's name as a constant string
    fn_call *call; // function call

} fn_record;

// the functions to be called and named
void fna() { printf("called fna\n"); }
void fnb() { printf("called fnb\n"); }
void fnc() { printf("called fnc\n"); }

// macro, that generates record for each function, it creates 
// string like { "fna", fna } to save You typing
#define FN_RECORD(f) { #f, f }

// now define array of functions records
fn_record fns[3] = {
    FN_RECORD(fna),
    FN_RECORD(fnb),
    FN_RECORD(fnc)
};

// ... which becomes:
// fn_record fns[3] = {
//     { "fna", fna },
//     { "fnb", fnb },
//     { "fnc", fnc }
// };


int main(void) {

    int i;

    // ... use it whatever You like
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        printf("%s\n", fns[i].name);
        fns[i].call();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. "Avoid typing" is _not_ a valid rationale for using function-like macros. Avoiding code repetition might be, but in that case you would use something like "x macros" and apply it to the whole program, not just the initialization list. Therefore, `FN_RECORD(fna)` should be replaced with the more readable and less cryptic `{"fna", fna}`.

Comment: (Ironically, somebody posted a x macros solution just seconds after I posted that comment)

Comment: @Lundin Well, this macro actually avoids code repetition. If renaming the function, the compiler will detect the bad table entry, but it cannot detect forgetting to adjust the string. The macro cares for you implicitly...

Comment: It only avoids some code repetition. If you were to implement a macro solution for that, you would use x macros as shown in another answer. But either should be avoided, it is mostly obfuscation for something that is simple and should be kept simple.

Comment: I agree. Generally, program's user shouldn't care for C functions names. OP should differentiate between his operation name and C function. Later he would want to rename his functions, but keep the program output intact. Like `{ "add", lib_high_math_add }`.

Comment: Your example has some new topics that I have to learn in C. Like the first typedef void fn_call();, this line has taken my interest right now I'm trying to understand how typedef affects the behavior of that declaration. I tried to remove typedef but it's very connected to the typedef declaration.

Comment: typedef is a new topic to me in C, I see it as a later topic, can I do your example without typedef? Aslo, can you explain to me the role of typedef in this code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no way.

```
// A function declaration
void MyFunction(void);

// a pointer to the function
void (*fnPointer)(void) = MyFunction;

// No way to retrieve function name "MyFunction" from fnPointer
```

Ofcourse, if you have a known set of possible functions that might be assigned to the pointer, you could compare them explicitely.

Also, you can change the stored function pointer to be combined with the function name. Could be something similar to the following:

```
struct FunctionPointerContainer
{
    void (*fnPointer)(void);
    char* fnName;
};

#define MakeFunctionPointer(fn) FunctionPointerContainer { fn, #fn }

// later
struct FunctionPointerContainer myPointer = MakeFunctionPointer(MyFunction);
myPointer.fnPointer(); // call
myPointer.fnName; // the function name
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was working of functions pointers examples

So, as I understand, your example is done **for educational purposes**, aren't you? In that case I would do it as simple as it can be to not confuse the students who use your example to learn how function pointers work.

> I learned about `__func__` and it only prints the name of the current function

Despite other answers show very nice and smart solutions how to have the function name outside of it, **from the perspective of simplicity** I would still use the [`__func__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) as it normally works, inside the called function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define print_info(format, ...) \
    printf("Function '%s' is called with parameters: "format"\n", \
    __func__, __VA_ARGS__)

int add(int x, int y);
int sub(int x, int y);
int mul(int x, int y);
int divide(int x, int y);

int main() {
    int m = 6, n = 10, i;    
    int (*fun[4])(int,int) = { add, sub, mul, divide };

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("-- result is: %d\n", fun[i](n, m));

    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y) {
    print_info("%d, %d", x, y);
    return x + y;
}

int sub(int x, int y) {
    print_info("%d, %d", x, y);
    return x - y;
}

int mul(int x, int y) {
    print_info("%d, %d", x, y);
    return x * y;
}

int divide(int x, int y) {
    print_info("%d, %d", x, y);
    return x / y;
}
```

Comment: Not for educational purposes, it's for me. I'm actually having troubles in my embedded programming, I want to program my Arduino board in C to communicate with HMC5883L, I did good job at developing the I2C and HMC5883L libraries, but I have a problem in the function which reads the data from the sensor, it actually crashes when the x-axis reaches a positive value, if you like I send you my topic link in Arduino exchange forum.

Comment: I did this function pointers example in this way because I want to have as much maneuverability as I can in C; like, doing things in different ways or the way I want.